# Check if page contents something after redirection - C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
actions.MoveToElement(input);
actions.Click();
actions.Build().Perform();
```

after that you get redirected to another page and the content there is available only after clicking that button. so my question is, how do i check if on that page that I got redirected on by using Selenium, there is something like 'Has been added' (if i just go to the URL again/refresh i will need to tap the button again)

Comment: Are you redirected to a different URL? Is there something on the new page that you can detect, like text?

Comment: @Greg yes, thats what im talking about. i need to detect that specific text that will not show after i refresh

Comment: Selenium will automatically wait for a page load.  If this is instead a javascript DOM update and not a full page load, use a webdriverwait for that element to appear.

Comment: Are you saying that after being redirected, you should see the text "Has been added"?